# Different Colors in a String using CSS only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there is a way to have words with different colours using only CSS (without using span).
For example:

```html
<h1>Red Blue Green</h1>
```

In above h1 tag, can I have Red in "red" colour, Blue in "blue" colour and Green in "green" colour?

Comment: Can you use multiple h1 tags? ```<h1>Red</h1><h1>Blue</h1><h1>Green</h1>``` Then, add id or class to each element.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not possible with CSS alone.**

You would have to write JavaScript to wrap each letter if you needed dynamic solution but if it's static title then you can just manually wrap each letter in `span` and style it.

Javascript + Regex:

```
$('h1').html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\d)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

Comment: Why the down vote? The question states only using CSS which is not possible so provided an answer to the question and how to do it if they wish to achieve it.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because the OP clearly states `only css` and `without using span in HTML`. Your answer ignores both requests. The correct approach would be to comment to the question saying that it's not possible with just CSS and that he would need additional ' help ' from  for eg javascript

Comment: @MihaiT Okay, in future I'll provide fallbacks in comments. Thanks :)

Comment: I don’t see what’s wrong here, it is stated that this is not possible using CSS alone - that answers the basic question. Suggesting an alternative, even if that is not exactly what was asked for, can’t be an actual “crime” in answering …?

Comment: @misorude Agreed, but on the other side of the coin I can understand Michai T statement. You don't want to pollute or derail with alternative more than answers.

Comment: @misorude everyone is free to give an answer like everyone is free to downvote/upvote .. no one is committing a "crime". Everyone is contributing

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing it with a vertical CSS gradient, kind of like this:

```
    h1 {
       background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3030 0%,#2e4bf2 3%,#27e524 6%); 
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

Instead of using the percentages, if you could figure out the width of the text and set the gradient stops there:

```
     h1 {
       background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3030 10px,#2e4bf2 10px,#27e524 10px); 
       -webkit-background-clip: text;
       -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use background coloration but it would be suitable for monospace font or it will be tedious to find the different values

```css
h1 {
 font-family:monospace;
 color:transparent;
 background:
  repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
    red 0 3ch,
    blue 3ch 8ch,
    green 8ch 14ch);
 -webkit-background-clip:text;
 background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<h1>Red Blue Green</h1>
```

Like below for each letter:

```css
h1 {
 font-family:monospace;
 color:transparent;
 background:
  repeating-linear-gradient(to right,
    red    0   1ch,
    blue   1ch 2ch,
    green  2ch 3ch,
    purple 3ch 4ch);
 -webkit-background-clip:text;
 background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<h1>Red Blue Green</h1>
```

Comment: How would this be achieved on dynamic content?

Comment: @Riddell what do you mean by *dynamic content*? I don't see anything related to this on the question

Comment: Sorry, have you ever made this work with dynamic content? Not relating to question

Comment: @Riddell still don't understand what *dynamic content* mean. I am coloring each letter and it will work whataver the content will be if we consider a monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, CSS has a single selector (:first-letter) for this. With this you can only define a style for the first letter.

Instead of dealing with CSS, you can use the [Splitting.js](https://github.com/shshaw/Splitting) library.

[Get Started](https://splitting.js.org/guide.html#get-started)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a gradient, mix-blend-mode or background-clip and a monospace font: inspired from https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZWMxdL & https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PNxPda

mix-blend-mode requires 2 element to mix background colors and text color.

```css
p {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, gray 0.5em, purple 1em, gold 1.5em, blue 2em, pink 2.5em, tomato 3em, lime 3.5em, brown 4em) 0 0;
  background-size: 4.25em 100%;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px white;
}

p~p {
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
}
/* DISCLAIMER */
body {background:#ddd;}
div {mix-blend-mode:screen;}
```

```html
<div>not avalaible yet for <b>'your browser',</b> please be patient.</div>
<p><span>span + mix-blend-mode <br>colorized text gradients colorized text gradients </span>  </p>
<hr>
<p> background-clip<br>  text gradients colorized text gradients   </p>
```

Answer (score -2):

No, that is not currently possible.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Like it or not, this is the correct answer to the OPs question.